# Is there a way I can integrate Firebase Database/Authentication with Stripe payments?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, server, stripe-payments

I'm building an iOS application that implements Firebase Authentication (so I have individual accounts for each user) and also Firebase Database, where I store all the user's information.

Initially, when I did research on how I was going to implement Stripe payments between users, I came across [this website](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customers) which talks about creating a user in Stripe. I was under the impression that I could send Stripe the user's card information so they could store it, and then store the returned id attached to the specific user. However, when I tried to do this, I realized that you can't just create a Stripe customer object within Swift, and you need a backend.

I then tried to follow [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments) on implementing Stripe and Firebase together, but it seems that I would need to upgrade my Firebase plan. Since this is just an idea I want to test out, I am not looking to pay extra.

I've been doing a lot of research to solve my problem, but since I am really new to the whole world of backend, I'm getting really lost in all the jargon.

Does anyone know any workarounds to integrate Firebase and Stripe? If not, can you recommend me a tutorial (that explains everything about servers haha) on how to create a server to handle Stripe?

Comment: I actually had the same question a few days ago so i ended up doing some research and found this firebase video by the firebase team https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeyxolsJ3aE using cloud function you can integrate stripe and listen to changes on your database to communicate with firebase, also check the video description there's a couple links including a GitHub one. another thing the example is using firestore but you can integrate it into firebase database if you don't want to transition to firestore. i hope this can help you. good luck